# How to create list of buttons in popup window flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create something like image. I thought its a popup dialog. Is it possible to achieve this in flutter? How it could be done?

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform them by adding a Basic `AppBar`. An `AppBar` is basically a toolbar that contains widgets within themselves for which action and `IconButton` can be assigned.

The below example will demonstrate the usage of `AppBar` in Flutter.

### Example

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
import '../my_route.dart'; 
class BasicAppbarExample extends MyRoute { 
    const BasicAppbarExample( 
          [String sourceFile ='lib/routes/appbar_basic_appbar_ex.dart'])
          : super(sourceFile);
 
    @override 
    get title => 'Basic AppBar'; 
  
    @override 
    get links => { 
    'Doc': 'https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html', 
  }; 
    
  @override 
    Widget buildMyRouteContent(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold( 
      appBar: AppBar(   
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent, 
        leading: Icon(Icons.tag_faces), 
        title: Text("Sample title"), 
        // TODO: add actions when items are clicked. 
        actions: <Widget>[ 
          IconButton( 
            icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike), 
            onPressed: () {}, 
          ), 
          IconButton( 
            icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bus), 
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          PopupMenuButton( 
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) { 
              return [ 
                PopupMenultem(child: Text('Boat')), 
                PopupMenultem(child: Text('Train'))
              ]; 
            },
          )
        ],
      ), 
      body: Center(child: Text("Hello")), 
    );
  }
```

#### How it'll look like?

[image: Output Image]

#### Reference

- [Flutter - AppBar class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html)

Edit: You can also other widgets to include images and login information (Pretty much anything you want)